Python program is not correctly downloading Sentinel-2 or Landsat images
I was working on a python program that can quickly download loads of satellite images using google earth api and geemap. My code is able to download tiff files, but the only problem is that they cannot be viewed in any tiff file viewer. It always states that the file is corrupted or too large. My code is given below:
import ee
import geemap
import os
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

# Initialize Earth Engine
ee.Initialize(project="your-earth-engine-project-id-here")

def download_landsat_image(lat, lon, output_folder, min_year='2020', max_year='2023', size=1000):
    try:
        point = ee.Geometry.Point([float(lon), float(lat)])
        region = point.buffer(size).bounds()
        
        collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2') \
            .filterBounds(region) \
            .filterDate(f'{min_year}-01-01', f'{max_year}-12-31') \
            .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 20))
        
        if collection.size().getInfo() == 0:
            print(f"No Landsat imagery available for coordinates: {lat}, {lon} between {min_year} and {max_year}")
            return None

        # Select bands and scale them
        def scaleImage(image):
            return image.select(['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2']).multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)

        image = collection.map(scaleImage).median()
        filename = f'landsat_image_{lat}_{lon}_{min_year}_{max_year}.tif'
        output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, filename)
        
        # Export the image to local filesystem
        geemap.ee_export_image(image.clip(region), filename=output_path, scale=30, region=region, file_per_band=False)
        
        print(f"Downloaded Landsat image: {output_path}")
        return output_path
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing coordinates: {lat}, {lon}. Error: {str(e)}")
        return None

def process_coordinates_file(file_path, output_folder, min_year='2020', max_year='2023', max_workers=5):
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
    
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        coordinates = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]
    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        future_to_coord = {executor.submit(download_landsat_image, lat, lon, output_folder, min_year, max_year): (lat, lon) for lat, lon in coordinates}
        
        for future in as_completed(future_to_coord):
            lat, lon = future_to_coord[future]
            try:
                result = future.result()
                if result:
                    print(f"Successfully processed: {lat}, {lon}")
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to process: {lat}, {lon}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception occurred for {lat}, {lon}: {str(e)}")
            
            # Add a small delay to avoid overwhelming the Earth Engine servers
            time.sleep(1)

# Usage
coordinates_file = 'coordinates.txt'
output_folder = 'landsat_images'
min_year = '2020'
max_year = '2023'
max_workers = 5

process_coordinates_file(coordinates_file, output_folder, min_year, max_year, max_workers)

Note, if you would like to run this program then you will need to install the libraries and authenticate earthengine by running earthengine authenticate in a terminal or ee.authenticate() in python. (It is only required once).
When I run this code, but change all instances of the dataset to USDA/NAIP/DOQQ (A UAV dataset for agricultural study in the contiguous US), it can download images correctly, and I can view them through any tiff viewing website or app. However, I would like to use sentinel-2 because of it's high spatial resolution and the fact that it has data for any place in the world.
I think that the problem here is that the python script or api for that matter cannot access the satellite images, or is downloading them in the wrong format. I was expecting to get Sentinel-2 images back from this script, but I get an invalid tiff file instead. Can you all help me?
Thanks,
Arnav
